# Async stream download in .net core

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-core

I encoutered a question here and need your help.

I had a .net web api project using PushStream to do async downloading, something like

```
new PushStreamContent(async (outputStream, httpContent, transportContext))=>{}
```

In this way, I can do multiple parts downloading in the action.

However, now I want to move the project into .net core and I cannot find a replacement in .net core for pushstream.

Could you please let me know is there something like pushstream in .net core or any methods to implement it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

`PushStreamContent` works by essentially setting a callback to be invoked when the output stream is being processed. This was necessary in ASP.NET Web Api because there was no direct access to `OutputStream`.

However, in ASP.NET Core, you do have direct access to the output stream via `HttpContext.Response.Body`. As a result, you can just directly write to that stream without needing something like `PushStreamContent`.

FWIW, while this can save some server resources, it's actually pretty bad, especially with something like an API. Since you're writing directly to the output stream, the headers are already sent, including the response status code. This means if there's any exception raised while you're writing, there's no opportunity to handle it appropriately. The response is simply aborted, and the client is left hanging with a supposedly "successful" response, and only a partial body. Personally, I would say avoid this practice altogether and take the resource hit. Unless you're streaming gigs of data, any good server setup will have a plentiful amount of RAM to handle what you're doing. Even then, there's probably better methods to handle delivering that data.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation, actually, I got some information from this blog https://blog.stephencleary.com/, which holds the same opinion as you, thanks again.

Comment: @ChrisPratt can you provide an example for the use in .NET Core?

Comment: Link to blog post: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/10/async-pushstreamcontent.html

Comment: A .net core example: https://dogschasingsquirrels.com/2020/06/02/streaming-a-response-in-net-core-webapi/